# Why can't i apply a second transformation to the same element using JS functions?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I'm building a memory game, where the player flips cells of different colors. When the second one is flipped, if there is no color match, they should flip back. The cells are flipping nicely to show their color, but they doesn't want to flip back, only the className is set by the flipBack() function.

```
const flipCell = cell => {
  cell.style.transform = "rotateY(360deg)";
  cell.style.transition = "transform .8s";
  setTimeout(() => {
    cell.className = "playCell flipped";
  }, 450);
};

const flipBack = (flippedCell1, flippedCell2) => {
  flippedCell1.style.transform = "rotateX(180deg)";
  flippedCell1.style.transition = "transform .8s";
  flippedCell2.style.transform = "rotateX(180deg)";
  flippedCell2.style.transition = "transform .8s";
  flippedCell1.className = "playCell unflipped";
  flippedCell2.className = "playCell unflipped";
};
```

Comment: can you please add your example with snippet?

Comment: This code comes from redux reducers, what i want to know is why the second transform and transition doesn't apply however the function is executed because the classname changes as expected

Comment: please at least add html code of your.